# <pre> tag VS. <br> tag for spacing

Tags: html, formatting, whitespace, pre

I'm interested in seeing the results of this.

If you want to have multiple spaces in text, you could do it in a few ways.

One way:

```
<p>&nbsp</p>
<p>&nbsp</p>
```

The next way:

```
<br/>
<br/>
```

And the last way:

```
<pre>




</pre>
```

Which one would be the best?

the pre tag also has the ability to put spacing horizontally, and it's a nice simple way:

```
<p>Home<pre>   </pre>About<pre>   </pre>Contact</p>
```

Answer (score 19, accepted):

None of the above. This is what CSS is for. Use CSS.

Addendum: if, for whatever reason, it has to be a purely HTML solution, I'd say they are all pretty much equal in nature as they are really all presentational rather than semantic. Seems like a 6/half dozen comparison.

Answer (score 6):

The key is semantics. Use what reflect better your intention.

Use `<p>` if you mean paragraphs. Use `<br/>` if you mean break lines. And use `<pre>`if you mean pre-formatted code.

Later, to "format", use CSS.

Comment: Very good answer.  Let's say that when you're formatting you decide that you want to space out some random text in a paragraph. What would you do?

Comment: @PearSquirrel If you want to change the line height in a paragraph, change the `line-height` CSS property.

Answer (score 1):

Yes as DA suggested you should use CSS (`word-spacing`, `letter-spacing`)for text spacing. you can use some thing like this:

```
p{
    word-spacing:30px;
}

p{
    letter-spacing:2px;
}
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Maybe I should have been clearer.  This is useful if you want the text to be uniform, but if there is a special instance where you simply want a spacer this can't be used.  I think you were thinking more about the navigation bar - what if you had a link that contained two words? ;)

Answer (score 1):

Use CSS, for example:

```
<p>
test
  test
</p>
```

with CSS

```
p { white-space: pre-wrap; }
```

http://jsfiddle.net/Vffmj/

Answer (score -1):

I would say that the `<br />` tag is actually better in this case for spacing purposes because it requires less code for the browser to parse.  while I understand that it's not much additional cod it's still a little be and in website performance the less you use the better.

However the more appropriate way to do this would just be to style padding around the elements.

just on a hunch but based on what you put there I think the most ideal way would be this:

```
<style type="text/css">
 #Navigation { padding: 0; margin: 0; }
 #Navigation li { float: left; list-style-type: none; display: inline-block; }
</style>

<ul id='Navigation'>
 <li>Home</li>
 <li>About</li>
 <li>Contact</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Servers don't parse HTML for the most part. The browser does.